# Insert values to jos_core_aro table

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

Where can I find in **Joomla 1.5** file system that file where in `jos_core_acl_aro`
and `jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map` table the values are inserted after registration ? Or some documentation for it.

I have a custom table with users(not `jos_users`). I want to display the user menu after login.

I think that the ACL system is querying the users from `jos_users`. I want to query them from my custom table and also insert my users values in those two acl tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two relevant files, where the ACL maps are touched.

- `administrator/components/com_users/views/users/view.html.php` (`UsersViewUsers`)
- `libraries/joomla/user/authorization.php` (`JAuthorization`)

The `JAuthorisation` class uses the `GACL` library in `libraries/joomla/phpgacl/`, which you can use to learn about the interna, but should only be used through `JAuthorisation`.